# How to create terminal program launcher (desktop shortcut)?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, shortcuts

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 win Unity 2D.

I want to have a launcher which launches application (sh file) which outputs many things to console.

`gnome-desktop-item-edit` can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run the command in a terminal. So creating a launcher that executes

`gnome-terminal -e yourscript.sh`

should do the trick.