# How to create a shortcut for terminal program on Xubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu, shortcuts, console

What is the analogue for [`gnome-terminal -e mc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/223792/169666) on Xubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical terminal commands are interchangeable. Use:

```
xfce4-terminal -e mc
```

This probably is true for all terminals that depend of `libvte9` and try to be a drop-in replacement for the venerable `xterm`.